# Blazor. Call webapi on startup

Tags: blazor

I’m wanting to make a http call to get the user profile settings and preferences before the application Ui is rendered. One of those settings is whether dark mode or light mode is enabled.

I can’t find anything about calling a web api to pull user settings prior to app starting.

Surely this must be a thing? I come from angular which has app initialiser that forces the application to call apis before boot loading has finished.

Comment: I have a similar need in my Blazor Server project.  What works for me, is to include my Web API service calls inside MainLayout.razor's OnInitializedAsync() method.  This allows me to get the necessary data before any components are rendered to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure how your components are structured - But if you have a Parent component, where the variables such as "UserTheme" are initialized, and Child components that also make use of this variable, then I would load the User Preferences from inside the Parent Component's OnInitializedAsync() method (I use AuthenticationState to get the current user), and then pass these to the child components as parameters.

Comment: @Daniël Hoffman, what you do is less than effective. Why starts rendering MainLayout, in the mid of which you perform Web API calls, and then re-renders the  MainLayout once again. You could create various claims, add them to the ClaimsPrincipal object you can access from  the AuthenticationState object. If you need to perform Web API calls, you can and should do that before your Blazor SPA is created; that is, to perform the Web API calls from the _Host.cshtml file, and pass retrieved data to the App component through the `component` Html helper, in the form of parameters.

Comment: The accepted parameters in the App component can then be passed to any other components on your SPA. You can define a service into which you can push the parameters passed  to `App`, and then inject the service in components that need that data

Comment: @John, can you elaborate on what challenge you're facing?  You should be able to easily do this in your `Program.cs` and simply make the call there.

Comment: My program.cs? I thought that was just where you register ioc dependencies? 

I’d sooner not make a http call in a constructor? 

My challenge is that the end point is a protected resource so the client needs to be authenticated first. Then I need to know once authenticated, whether the user wants dark mode or not. This needs to happen prior to any UI rendering.

Comment: Are you on a WASM or Server project? And which version of .NET?

Comment: @ConnorLow here from Google, I am on Blazor WASM with the same needs. I dont want to use claims as my settings are not user-related but rather whole app-related.

Answer (score 0):

In your Program.cs split the code like this:

```cs
var host = builder.Build();

// Call your web api:
var httpClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
var x = await httpClient ...

// Finish startup:
await host.RunAsync();
```